# Cannot deploy iOS 10 app on new iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to try an app on my new iPhone. 
If I connect to XCode my iPhone 6S everything is ok, the app run on the device.

When I use the iPhone 7 I have this error:

```
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.xxx.test" doesn't include the currently selected device "iPhone 7".
```

And of course

```
Automatic provisioning failed
```

I'm not an Xcode expert, how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using Xcode 8? If not, upgrade.

Comment: If you are using xcode 8, then go to preferences and select account than click on '+' at the bottom and add new apple ID and than add the apple id that is in your iphone 7. click ok. Now go to general in from your project navigation bar and select team with named your apple id. and than click on resolve issues. and run the application. @RobertoPezzali

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your device manually in your developer account and then download the updated profile to xcode, and make sure that you have the latest xcode.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a paid account. How can I add my device manually?

Comment: If you are using xcode 8, then go to preferences and select account than click on '+' at the bottom and add new apple ID and than add the apple id that is in your iphone 7. click ok. Now go to general in from your project navigation bar and select team with named your apple id. and than click on resolve issues. and run the application. @RobertoPezzali

Comment: In this case you can't add manually, try to clean up your project using (Command + option + shift + K) and check on your project navigator settings if the "Automatically manage signing" box is checked.

Comment: Nothing, I already try. Nothing to do. I think that the problem is that I have a paid account that now is expired...